# UICollectionView get crash in Xcode 6.1 Works fine in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uicollectionviewcell, xcode6.1

[image]when i run my project in `XCode6.1` i am getting this exception when `UICollectionview` get load the `custom cell`. it work fine in `Xcode 5.1.1`. Thanks in advance

Comment: check that your reuse identifier is problem

Comment: do you have an outlet called `description` in your customCell? What is that label?

Comment: hi anil, ya that is a label. y?

Comment: That is connected properly?

Comment: Thank you anil issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know as per Xcode 6.1 you should not have an outlet called `description` since it will contradict with the primary member(most of the classes already have a string property called `description`). So better you change the name of the outlet something like `descriptionLabel`. And reconnect the outlet. This will fix the issue i guess.